# How to Use Joined Tables When querying a LinkedServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have a Linked Server `LinkedServer1` I'd like to query using Joined tables.

My query example:

```
   SELECT     dds.Invoice_Tb.Store_Number, dds.Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number,
                 dds.Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number AS Invoice
      FROM      [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Tb INNER JOIN
                [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Detail_Tb ON 
                [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number = 
                [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number
```

This Query, when executed gives me an error:

```
The multi-part identifier could not be bound for each of the above table references.  It references each table and column listed above.
```

How do you properly query data using Table Joins with a linked server?

Comment: You should try **aliases** for tables

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Can you throw up an answer and I'll accept it?  Thanks @IvanStarostin

Comment: You can upvote my comment. There is already @JassyJov's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use alias:

```
select  a.Store_Number,
        a.Invoice_Number,
        a.Invoice_Number as Invoice
from    [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Tb as a
        inner join [LinkedServer1].Database1.dds.Invoice_Detail_Tb  as b on
           a.Invoice_Number = b.Invoice_Number
```

Comment: Might suggest using the `REMOTE` hint if appropriate as well.